# Why does it work? JS function and var

Tags: javascript, function, variables

In the middle of writing some JS, and the script worked exactly as i had expected it to, BUT before i had even given it the number to work with.

Now the number IS stated further along the script, and i am just curious, is that why this works??  Does a variable in JS take into account vars that are declared later along inside a function?

The specific part im confused about: `if (lastrowIDnumInt === 0)` because the var is not declared and given a value until the else.

Please if anyone could explain if this is correct to work and if so, a reference as to why?

Heres the snippet:

```
function voidall() {

    if (lastrowIDnumInt === 0){ // references lastrowIDnumInt, no tengo como haces without prior reference
        alert("You cannot remove any items that do not exist!");
    } else {
        var activetableID = $("li.till_table_button.active").attr('id');
        // alert(activetableID);
        var tablenumber = $("#"+activetableID).data("tableref");
        // alert(tablenumber); //testing

        var lastrowid = $( "#till__tablepanel_table_"+tablenumber+" tr:last").attr("id");
        var idReference = lastrowid.substr(0, lastrowid.indexOf('row_')); //gets the beggining id refernces without number
        // alert(idReference); //testing
        var fullReference = idReference+"row_";
        // alert(fullReference); //testing
        var lastrowIDnum = lastrowid.substring(lastrowid.indexOf("row_") + 4); //take number for row by removing string contents
        lastrowIDnumInt = parseInt(lastrowIDnum); //turn string number into integer

        while ( lastrowIDnumInt > 0 ) {
            $( "#till__tablepanel_table_"+tablenumber+" tr:last").remove();
            lastrowIDnumInt--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of [JavaScript hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)?

Comment: By the way,this is why JSLint specifies that all variables should be declared first thing in a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All `var` declarations in a function are treated as if they appeared at the top of the function. It's called "hoisting".

Note that it's the *declaration* that's treated like it's at the top, not the *initialization*. That means:

```
function foo() {
  if (something === 0) {
    alert("zero");
  }
  else {
    var something = 0;
    alert("not zero"); // <-- this
  }
}
```

That's treated as if it looked like this:

```
function foo() {
  var something;
  if (something === 0) { // <-- undefined here
    alert("zero");
  }
  else {
    something = 0;
    alert("not zero"); // <-- this
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, ok, i learned something amazing today. I had no idea about this, this will open my mind somewhat with JS. Many thanks.

Comment: @StuartWickenden great!  This is why a lot of people discourage `var` declarations inside conditional code (`if`, `while`, etc). Even for people who know about hoisting, it makes reading code a little confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Because `var` is hoisted to the top of the function scope. In other words, your variables are all *defined* regardless of the conditional, but they'll only be assigned values in the `else` block.